# Star rating of electrical appliances like AC / fridge

Tags: efficiency

What distinguishes a 2-star rated AC/fridge from the one rated 5-star? What exactly is the technical reason for the difference in their efficiencies? Is it the compressor technology / the wiring / better electronics or something else?

Comment: What star-rating regime are you referring to? Link please.

Comment: I don't know about other countries, but here in India, we have star ratings for electrical appliances. Here is a link which might help.. https://pricebaba.com/blog/bee-star-ratings-in-home-appliances

Comment: I'm sorry but having scanned through the reasons for star ratings, its clear that you cannot consider A versus B given that A may have gotten 5 stars 2 years ago and B only got 3 stars one month ago. This makes it a fairly non-EE question - I suggest you read that link and invent a better scenario that might be answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The star rating is a method of comparing energy usage of similar appliances over some period of time like a billing cycle or a year. That is related to efficiency, but not the same thing. For a fridge, the motor efficiency would be one important factor and the coefficient of performance of the refrigeration system would be another. Those are both related to energy used for cooling. Just as important is the thermal insulation and sealing of the door which prevent heat from entering the fridge from the outside. Those factors can be analyzed using engineering methods. For evaluation, an assumption needs to be made about how often the door is opened and how long it remains open. An assumption also need to be made about things being put in the fridge that are initially warmer than the internal temperature. That assumption would need to be equivalent for all products evaluated, but individual people are likely to use the product differently and experience different results.

The electrical and electronic control design may influence the efficiency of some appliances, but the motor design and the non-electrical aspects of the design are likely to be the most important factors.

Comment: The recent gains, over the past 20 or so years, in performance of fridges and freezers has been the use of microprocessors and more accurate temperature sensors, replacing the original bi-metallic strip...